# Transferring game data between accounts on separate PS3 units

Tags: ps3

I was playing Diablo III on my brother in-law's PS3.  I got to act II.  My email address for that account got hacked and Google locked it and closed it.  I can't remembered the password for that account anyway.  I can still access it on his system though.  I recently got my own PS3 and created a new account with my new email address and want to transfer my game data to my system and account.  Any suggest?

Comment: This is really more of a Gmail issue which is off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Well since the original email was closed and you forgot the password to it, there really is no other way of game sharing it to your new PS3. you`re probably going to have to get a new copy of Diablo III, or try to remember the password of your old email and hope that it is still up.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the save file of the game is not directly associated with the account. If you want to upload it to the cloud you'd need to use the same account to download it on other device, but if you copy the save file on a physical usb drive you can use it on any other account/system you want.
Try copying it on a USB and then copying it to your own system on any account, it won't cost to try. The worst thing that can happen is you won't earn any trhophies for that game whilst using that save file.
It may say that the save file can only be used by the owner, in that case all you need to do is change the name that appears on the "User Log in Screen" of your PS3 to match your user name on the other system, or create a new user with no PSN verification just to play Diablo.